# Replace names of variables with their values in a string

Tags: vb.net, replace, formula

Suppose I've got a couple of classes, like `class1` and `class2`. These classes can have many properties and they can even change from an execution to another (depending on the version of the software).

The user can define a "formula" in plain text and the software should convert the names of the "variables" (class+property) with their actual values. So, given an instance of `class1` and an instance of `class2`, I should cycle the properties (and variables) and check if the formula contains them. For each one I should then replace the name with the value.

For example, I could have:

```
Dim myClass1 As Class1 = New Class1()
myClass1.PropertyA = "FOO"
myClass1.PropertyB = 5

Dim myClass2 As Class2 = New Class2()
myClass2.PropertyX = "BAR"
myClass2.PropertyY = 7
```

And the user could have declared this formula (the formula here is simplified in VB.NET, but actually it can be in SQL or different type. The formula is in plain text, so is a string in code):

```
Dim i = 0
While (i + myClass1.PropertyB) < myClass2.PropertyY
    str = "myClass1.PropertyA" & "myClass2.PropertyX"
    i += 1
End While
```

The result, after the replace, should be:

```
Dim i = 0
While (i + 5) < 7
    str = "FOO" & "BAR"
    i += 1
End While
```

Now, the classes and the variables can vary, so I can't search for specific strings. I think I should use reflection, but I'm not used to it and I prefer to avoid it if a better solution exists. Any advice and/or best practice?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as a class or as a function
Consider the formula.
x=(a*a)+(b*b)+(2*a*b)

```
Public Function formularesult(Byval a1 as double,Byval b1 as double) as double
Dim x as double
x=0
Dim a as double
a=0
Dim b as double
b=0
a =a1
b=b1
x=(a*a)+(b*b)+(2*a*b)
return x
End Function
```

Call to the function can bs follows
Let values of a and b can be 12 and 20 respectively.

```
Dim result as double
result =formularesult(12,20)
```

I hope this can be a help for someone.

Improvements to my suggestions are always welcome.